# Can't figure out what did I miss here, it says 'list' is not a valid function. Any help would be appreciated

Tags: django

The error that occurs during template rendering:

> In template /Users/mac/myfirstproject/templates/base_layout.html, error at line 12
>   Reverse for 'list' not found. 'list' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>ARTICLES</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1><a href="{% url 'list' %}"><img src="{% static 'logo.png' %} "/></a></h1>
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: '''<!DOCTYPE html>
3 <html lang="en">
4 <head>
5     <meta charset="UTF-8">
6     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
7     <title>ARTICLES</title>
8     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}">
9 </head>
10 <body>
11     <div class="wrapper">
12         <h1><a href="{% url 'list' %}"><img src="{% static 'logo.png' %} "/></a></h1>
13         {% block content %}
14         {% endblock %}
15     </div>>
16 </body>
17 </html>'''

Comment: the number indicates line, right?

Comment: Reverse for 'list' not found means that there is no pattern name in your urls.py file that matches 'list'. My guess is that you forgot to add the namespace. E.g. if this 'list' pattern name belongs to some app named 'products', you would call it in your templates like so:`{% url 'products:list' %}`. Also make sure that the namespace 'products' is specified in products/urls.py: `app_name = 'products'` (I am assuming here that you use `include` function in your main urls.py file)

Comment: @MKPatel yes, the numbers indicates the line in html.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in Andrei's comment above, you need to make sure you have 'list' set up as a valid url name in your urls.py file.

something like this:

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import list_view


urlpatterns = (
    url(r'^list$', list_view, name='list'),
)
```

in order to use the `{% url 'url_name' %}` template tag, you have to have a url named `url_name`, and if you have your project divided into apps, the format is:
`{% url 'app_name:url_name' %}. If you post your urls.py file, perhaps we can be more helpful.